# How to efficiently store game data in a URL query string?

Tags: javascript, compression

### Background

I have written a simple WebGL puzzle game and I want to allow people to design and share their own levels.

My idea was to store the level data in the query string of a URL.  This would then let people simply share the URL if they wanted a friend to try the level.

What is a good way to store game data in a query string?

### What I've tried

Currently I generate a URL via

```
"penguins.html?data="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify([X,P]));
```

This first converts the data to JSON:

```
[[[[3,-1,0,0,0],[4,-1,0,0,0]]],[{"x":20,"y":20,"dx":0,"dy":0,"vy":2.9999999871229686,"vx":0.0002779607689814708,"thetaf":180,"speed":3,"type":0,"state":6,"steps":0,"numfish":0,"d":4,"size":8},{"x":60,"y":60,"dx":20,"dy":100,"vy":97.51615330485151,"vx":-78.06665276994102,"thetaf":0,"speed":3,"type":17,"state":0,"steps":0,"numfish":0,"d":15,"size":89.00000012433019}]]
```

and then escapes it to become:

```
[[[[3%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C0]%2C[4%2C-1%2C0%2C0%2C0]]]%2C[{%22x%22%3A20%2C%22y%22%3A20%2C%22dx%22%3A0%2C%22dy%22%3A0%2C%22vy%22%3A2.9999999871229686%2C%22vx%22%3A0.0002779607689814708%2C%22thetaf%22%3A180%2C%22speed%22%3A3%2C%22type%22%3A0%2C%22state%22%3A6%2C%22steps%22%3A0%2C%22numfish%22%3A0%2C%22d%22%3A4%2C%22size%22%3A8}%2C{%22x%22%3A60%2C%22y%22%3A60%2C%22dx%22%3A20%2C%22dy%22%3A100%2C%22vy%22%3A97.51615330485151%2C%22vx%22%3A-78.06665276994102%2C%22thetaf%22%3A0%2C%22speed%22%3A3%2C%22type%22%3A17%2C%22state%22%3A0%2C%22steps%22%3A0%2C%22numfish%22%3A0%2C%22d%22%3A15%2C%22size%22%3A89.00000012433019}]]
```

### Drawback of current approach

This approach works fine for small levels, but for bigger levels I get the error:

```
414. That’s an error.

The requested URL /penguins.html... is too large to process.
```

It seems that my current host (Google Appengine) has a limit on the length of the URL.

### Question

Is there a better way in Javascript to store my game data (i.e. which would result in a shorter URI)?

Comment: Are those data parsed and used by the server or the client?

Comment: The data is parsed by the client in Javascript using JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(...))

Comment: I imagined that, since the page's extension is "html", but maybe it's preprocessed anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something similar where I make a POST to GAE with the JSON data and store it in the datastore with a generated key and return a url based on that key for the user to share.

So you make your post of the JSON data.  You store that data in an object like:

```
/* Annotations ommitted */
public class GameInfo {
    public JSONObject gameData;
    public Integer key;
}
```

The `key` is an auto generated `int`.  Then you return to the user a url like: `http://www.mygameurl.com/games?id=1234` with id corresponding to the generated `key`.  Then you can let the user share that url to get the game data back from the datastore.  It shortens the url that the user is sharing and prevents them from messing with the url and breaking the game data.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the proper grown-up way to solve the problem.  I was just trying to avoid having to store the data myself.

Comment: I tried the url at first as well but as my data grew, so did my problems.  Doing it this way allowed me to scale my data without having to rewrite my sharing url structure. Also, you might have to store the gameData as a String instead of a JSONObject but I can't remember exactly if the datastore will take a JSONObject or not.  I typically stick to basic types.

Comment: This seems the best way of getting a really short URL for sharing. Thanks for your help (now time to learn about the datastore...)

Answer (score 3):

Since the data are parsed and used by the client, you don't need to actually send those data to the server. So, instead of using the query string, use the hash part of the url:

```
"penguins.html#" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify([X, P]));
```

Notice the `#`. Now you can parse the date back using:

```
JSON.parse(location.hash.substring(1));
```

Comment: Just tried it out and it works great in both Firefox and Chrome.  Thanks again for the lateral thinking!

Comment: This is probably the best and most usable answer for the OP's use case. Plus, you don't need to store anything in the datastore, which is a huge savings for the developer.

Comment: While a good solution and definitely results in savings for the dev, part of the question was asking for a shorter url.  The dev is also planning on having people share these urls and a very long url, even with the hash, isn't very friendly for sharing.  Most people prefer to share bit.ly links than they do absurdly long urls.  If sharing wasn't part of the equation, I'd definitely agree that this is the best solution, hands down.

Comment: @MCeley Yes, you are right. Also, bit.ly would only shorten URLs less than ~3200 bytes long, so even if the OP adds an auto-shorten URL feature, he or she would hit a ceiling in URL length sooner or later.

Comment: Of course my solution is good only for big-but-not-huge amounts of data. If Peter plans to store 4K of data or more, then he can either try to use some more compact notation instead of JSON, or try to use arrays instead of objects. But if it's still not enough, then MCeley's solution is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the game in a sql database and point the url to its ID on the DB to load it.

Or if you want, but more complicate, pack the url in a binary data and show it as a base64, so just need to unpack it to load  the game.

Comment: Thanks, is there an equivalent to JSON.stringify that would turn my data into binary?  Perhaps something that compresses the string as well?

Comment: Base64 encoding the url data will actually increase the url size which will cause the same problem that the poster is already having.

Comment: @MCeley that's why I talked to convert it on binary before, 4 bits for a float, 1 bit for a char, 2 bit for a short, ... and after convert to base64.
Peter de Rivaz try to see with jDataView since it's a cross browser lib to get binary data.

Comment: If you pack the url down so that 1 bit represents a char, how are you storing the value of that char?  If you mean 1 byte for a char then that's already the format of the data and wouldn't actually compress anything.  Not trying to discredit the idea, maybe I just don't understand what you're proposing.

Comment: The idea is to have a structure like games assets, no properties, just data. So you remove all the string x/y/step/type/etc. and pack all data in the right order.

Comment: I see what you're talking about.  You just align the data in the right order so you don't have to put identifiers on what type of data is there.  The problem with that is that if the data scales too large then you could still have a url that is too long.  It'd most likely work in the short term but it sounds like more of a band-aid solution instead of a long term fix.  Still pretty clever though, I wouldn't have thought to do it like that.

Comment: Yeah of course it depend if there is a lot of informations to store, and if they are some facultative informations (and the structure should not change for a while - or have to put a version info in the data). If it's too big, better to use the sql database I talked about :p

Comment: Good point, in my case I suspect the data format may well change so I don't want to get stuck in a particular format (whether Json or binary) and the database idea seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of game that you are developing, but in some cases, particularly in a deterministic puzzle game, it might be more efficient to store the steps leading to a particular game state rather than storing the entire state itself.

For example, say you are making a chess game, you could save a board state by saving the steps (e4,e5;f4,exf4;Bc4...) rather than the position of all chess pieces in the board. If your initial game state is procedurally generated, you could also save the intial seed of the game on the URL.

In this way, when a request with a particular URL is received by your servlet, the servlet could recompute the end state by redoing all the steps from the given URL.